# How can I make these 2 <p> elements stick together?

Tags: html

Image:

[image]

Here is the code

```
<p class="red">
    <font color="white">404 Not Found</font>
</p>
<p class="green">
    <font color="white">Try Again</font>
</p>
```

And I want the red and green one stick together, not leave a space between them

Comment: `<p>` tags come with margins by default. Just remove it with `margin:0`

Comment: Alright thanks, it worked

Comment: The `<font>` element doesn't exist in HTML5. Use CSS.

Comment: I'm not working on HTML5

Comment: HTML5 is the standard for today, so you really can't avoid it. And `<font>` won't exist going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `margin` to `0`

```css
p{
  margin:0;
  padding:5px 10px;
}
.red{
    background-color:red;  
}
.green{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<p class="red"><font color="white">404 Not Found</font></p><p class="green"><font color="white">Try Again</font></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `span` instead of `p`
`<p><span style="background:red"><font color="white">404 Not Found</font></span><span style="background:green"><font color="white">Try Again</font></span></p>`

Comment: I prefer using CSS

Comment: Use it! `<p><span class="red"><font color="white">404 Not Found</font></span><span class="green"><font color="white">Try Again</font></span></p>`